# how to create virtual url path in static site? javascirpt html

Tags: javascript, html, static, github-pages

does anyone know if this is possible

i have static site in github pages
https://username.github.io

i want to create virtual url path, not in github repo
like
https://username.github.io/search/something
and do something with javascript

please help. can it be done?
Thanks a lot.

javascript
html
github

Comment: Please, explain more what you want to achieve.